# Can I disable Log management in Log Analytics Workspace for AKS?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

Can I disable Log management in Log Analytics Workspace for AKS?

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can do that with:

```
az aks disable-addons -a monitoring -n MyExistingManagedCluster -g MyExistingManagedClusterRG
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-optout) you can find the docs for this.